# Is it ok to use spinlocks with O(1) non-memory contiguous code?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, spinlock

I'm using spinlocks (*pthread* ones) with *generally* **O(1)** list element access/removal in the locked code section.

I say *generally* because on 99.9% of cases the code doesn't loop through the list (which might contain 1000+ elements).
The code will usually extract one only element based on a list element *hint* pointer and then perform a couple of *if* branches to modify the cited *hint* element; still it should be a non contiguous access to memory.

Is it a good idea to use spinlocks or should I move to mutexes?

I'm aiming at max performance, don't care about CPU (over) usage in this context.

Cheers

Comment: Benchmark. I don't think anyone can answer this for you with the details you give.

Comment: what do you mean performance?  i thought cpu usage is performance...

Comment: @thang: No, with a spinlock, CPU usage can be just heating up the room.

Comment: huh?  performance can mean many things.  the question is what do you mean when you want max performance...

Comment: You use a spin lock where the tasks are lightweight, so that a context swapping is more  expensive than an active waiting.

Comment: Definitely compare with a normal pthread mutex. The normal mutex already does an intelligent amount of spinning before resorting to a system call, and I imagine you'd be hard-pressed to come up with a cleverer strategy yourself.

Comment: @Emanuele What performance parameter are you looking for? Throughput? If it's throughput you are optimizing for, you should optimizie the time the object is locked. The information "O(1)" only tells us that your task is completed in constant time. There is no information if your task completes "fast".  So the more important question before every other question is WHAT you are locking not how you are locking.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think mutex lock does any busy-spinning, at least with `pthreads` in `glibc`.

Comment: I believe it all boils down to how long I'm going to keep the lock eventually, right? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for short critical sections (like where it just updates list pointers) spin lock may be preferred.

With little contention there should be little difference between spin locks and mutexes because the non-contended path is heavily optimized in the latter.

The difference comes when a critical section becomes contended. When the mutex is taken, locking it blocks the thread and takes it off the scheduler run queue taking it much longer to wake up and lock the mutex when it is eventually released, whereas a spin lock would just spin in the hope that the spin lock is released shortly.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some benchmarks with reproducible test cases, switching between *pthread mutex* and *spinlock* implementation, I can say the if mutex uses a bit less CPU, the *spinlock* implementation is twice as fast in processing the elements off the queue.

I believe the correct answer, given the **O(1)** nature of the function processing the list and the fact this (mostly) *constant* time is *tiny*, favours the *spinlock* choice vs. *mutex*.

So if one wants to achieve max performance, doesn't care about CPU wasted cycles, *spinlocks* are preferable vs *mutexes* in case the protected code execution time is *tiny* (and better *constant*).